# Building a dataframe by parsing character vectors in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm new to R and struggling with the construction of a dataset out of a museum's collection.

After scraping their website, I have a list of character vectors (let's say the name is "characteristics") in which each element looks like this:

```
[[4729]]
[1] " Date://2002 Medium://Pencil on paper Dimensions://22 1/2 x 30 1/8\" (57.2 x 76.5 cm) Credit Line://The Judith Rothschild Foundation Contemporary Drawings Collection Gift MoMA Number://1563.2005 Copyright://© 2015 Steve DiBenedetto"
```

from these vectors, I want to make a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     year    medium           dimensions    credit line    number
1   2002     Pencil on paper   etc...
```

However, I can't seem to manage to substract the necessary data out of the character vectors as I'm struggling with the regex's to do this. The idea would be to fetch what comes after "Date://" and before "Medium://". To make matters more complicated, not every element in the list has the same characteristics in the same order (e.g. some elements only have "date" and "medium" while others include "edition://", "acquired through://", etc).

A list of the years was pretty easy to compile by just saving the first 4 digits in each list element:

```
year <- list()

for(p in 1:length(characteristics)) {
  string <- as.character(characteristics[p])
  year <- c(year, str_extract(string, "\\d\\d\\d\\d"))
  }
```

This is probably not even the fastest way to do it, but it does the job well.
However, I'm completely stuck on extracting the other variables out of the list.

Comment: Any chance preprocessing using `awk` or something is allowed?

Comment: You could extrac thte string and then use `gsub` to remove the first matching part.. Match for this regex every step: `[a-zA-Z]*:\/\/\([^\/]* \)[A-Za-z]*\/\/`. Beware that this regex is in sed syntax. There is a group capture, which contains the info you want, access it using `\1` or `\\1` I believe in `R`.

Comment: Do you know the available options for the range of characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe good old `read.table` is an option, too:

```
txt <- c("Date://2002 Medium://Pencil on paper Dimensions://22 1/2 x 30 1/8\" (57.2 x 76.5 cm) Credit Line://The Judith Rothschild Foundation Contemporary Drawings Collection Gift MoMA Number://1563.2005 Copyright://© 2015 Steve DiBenedetto",
         "Date://2002 Medium://Pencil on paper Dimensions://22 1/2 x 30 1/8\" (57.2 x 76.5 cm) Credit Line://The Judith Rothschild Foundation Contemporary Drawings Collection Gift MoMA Number://1563.2005 Copyright://© 2015 Steve DiBenedetto")
read.table(text = gsub("( Credit)?\\s?[A-z]+://", "\t", txt), sep = "\t", quote = "", col.names = letters[1:7])[-1]
#      b               c                                 d                                                                           e      f                        g
# 1 2002 Pencil on paper 22 1/2 x 30 1/8" (57.2 x 76.5 cm) The Judith Rothschild Foundation Contemporary Drawings Collection Gift MoMA 1563.2 © 2015 Steve DiBenedetto
# 2 2002 Pencil on paper 22 1/2 x 30 1/8" (57.2 x 76.5 cm) The Judith Rothschild Foundation Contemporary Drawings Collection Gift MoMA 1563.2 © 2015 Steve DiBenedetto
```

Comment: This is getting close @lukeA! However, some issues still standing: we lose the information about which characteristic we're saving (e.g. "medium"). Different artworks have different characteristics, so I should be able to save the characteristics under the right column name. So, the information we store should be stored in a column named with the string before the `://` (e.g. "medium"). I don't have a list of the range of characteristics, like @Anando Mahto suggested here. Whenever we encounter a new tag before the `://`, a new column should be made with that name.